# Dividing numeric data types result as different scaled numeric type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 numeric type variable. I want to devide this variables. But I want result is Numeric(5,2).

For example:

```
DECLARE @DISCOUNT_PRICE numeric(9,2) = '436.63' 
DECLARE @PRICE numeric(9,2) = '1.2'

SELECT CAST((((@DISCOUNT_PRICE*100)/@PRICE) -100 ) AS NUMERIC(5,2))
```

Variables (9,2) I want result as (5,2)

When I ran this code, I get an error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Thanks for the help.

Comment: See [Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670903/arithmetic-overflow-error-converting-numeric-to-data-type-numeric)

Comment: The result of that query is `36285.833333333333`, how do you fit that into a `decimal(5,2)`? The largest number that can hold is `999.99`.

Comment: I know the problem but. Is there a way to cast numeric(9,2) to numeric(5,2)

Comment: Yes, by having a number that **fits**. `DECLARE @n numeric(9,2) = 123.25; SELECT CONVERT(numeric(5,2),@n);` works fine.

Comment: `36285.83~` is too large for a `numeric(5,2)`. You can't push a circular block through a smaller circular hole; you have to make to hole bigger or the block smaller. So you either need to make the size of the datatype bigger (the hole), or make the number (the block) smaller to fit.

Comment: You can get rid of after 2 decimal (without rounding). doesnt matter. Is there a way ? @Larnu

Comment: Is there a way to what? `36285.83` will **never** fit into a `numeric(5,2)`. It's `35285.84` too large (as I said, the largest value you can fit is `999.99`). The smallest size numeric you could use to fit `36285.83` would be `numeric(7,2)`. If you don't care about the decimal points, you could use a `numeric(5,0)`.

Comment: i am having a big enlightenment right now. all these years :DD i thought that the first number was length of before dot (.) (7,2) works thank you!